# Foundation basics, scss, js and bower components

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

1. Can I compile scss from project folder created with `foundation new project` with sass?
2. Why js folder had only `app.js` file, should I move files from `bower_components/foundation/js`to `(root)/js` or link to their folder?
3. Should user css settings includes in app.css or custom file that includes app.css?
4. In bootstrap sass files collected in one folder, why in foundation scss folder had only app.scss and other files in bower components.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you install Foundation this way, you use the SCSS folder created that contains the _settings.scss & app.scss. The app.scss is what you tend to use as your base SCSS file to compile from so you'd include all your other SCSS files to this one. You can move this file to elsewhere if you please but move the config.rb with it and make sure the add_import_path works from where you move it to.
2. You don't need to move the files, everything in bower_components should never be touched or moved, they are there so they can be upgraded when necessary, you shouldn't have to touch base Foundation files.
3. I said before you should use that, but you could include the app.scss into a custom scss file but it's better to have control of the Foundation imports in 1 file, in my opinion.
4. For the same reason i mentioned in 2, so you don't touch them and Bower can easily update them if you require.